# Newbie Question for power supply

Tags: power

I am sorry if I am asking a basic question here but have no idea what I am talking about  :).

My question is this:

I have a digital camera that requires DC supply.
I have a couple of power supplies but not sure if either are any good.

On the camera it states:
DC12W 5Watt Max

On power supply 1:
INPUT 100-240 VAC 50/60Hz 0.5A
OUTPUT +12V 1A

On power supply 2:
INPUT 100-240 VAC 50/60Hz 0.8A
OUTPUT +5V 4

Are either power supplies powerful enough or are they too much?

Thanks

Comment: is it 12W or 12V on the cam?

Comment: I would think it's 12V on camera, which at 5W max would be under 500mA. So the power supply 1 would work. You need to match the voltage rating, the current rating of the power supply just has to be higher than the current requirement of the camera.

Comment: I assume that's 12V, so 5W gives you 5/12 = 0.42A, so any power supply that outputs 12VDC and can supply A >= 0.42A will work.

Comment: Hi chaps. Thanks for trying to help me.  It says DC12V and 5W MAX on cam

Comment: I suggest looking at the best answer to this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Specifically the Voltage Rating and Current Rating sections.

Comment: Well 5 W max means that the camera will draw at most 5W, so your first power supply should work fine

Comment: @everyone. Thank you all for being so helpful. Much appreciated!

Comment: @AndrewSimpson For future reference.  Questions about use of electronics (especially consumer electronics) are off-topic on EE.SE .

Comment: @NickAlexeev Hi, i had no idea that was the case. This was my 1st foray on this forum. I will delete this question if you deem appropriate? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I bet that on the camera it states "DC12**V**" 5Watt Max.
If i'm right, use the power supply 1. If it is +12V 1A rated it means it can deliver 12Watt, so you have more than enough power.

Comment: I am about to give it a go :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Just make sure the polarity on the cam and the power supply is the same (the little circle-in circle marking with + and -)